# Enable and disable EditorFor control used to make DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have generated a MVC application in which I have created DateTimePicker control using html helper EditorFor control and JQuery.

Below is the line of DateTime picker  control

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClosedTime)
```

Also I have one DropdowmFor control based on which selection I want to make EditorFor control as enable or disable.

Initially when my page loads I make the control disabled using below JQuery statement

```
$('#ClosedTime').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

This statement works fine and it disables the control, now as I said before I want to make the EditorFor control enable and disable based on the selection of DropdownFor control.

I tried this by writing below script.

```
$('#selectedRequestStatus').change(function () {
            var selectedRequest = $(this).val();

            if (selectedRequest == "C") {
                //alert('Closed');
                $('#ClosedTime').attr('disabled', 'enable');

            }
            else {
                //alert('In Progress');
                $('#ClosedTime').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            }
        });
```

Where selectedRequestStatus is the Dropdown control as I mentioned before.

But this script doesn't work.

Please let us know your suggestions for the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your issue is in the jQuery... try this:

```
$('#selectedRequestStatus').change(function () {
    var selectedRequest = $(this).val();

    if (selectedRequest == "C") {
        //alert('Closed');
        $('#ClosedTime').removeProp('disabled');
    }
    else {
        //alert('In Progress');
        $('#ClosedTime').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

In HTML, the presence of the `disabled` attribute makes the control 'disabled'. By removing it completely it enables the control.

Comment: Hi Michael,  Thank you for the quick reply. Yes I can say its working for me. Thank you again.